# Promisifying an synchorous function

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

So, I have a code which is something like this.

```
     getSomethingAsync(something)
     .then(doSomethingAsync)
     .then(function(d) {
     _d = doSomethingSync(d);
     return doSomethingAsyncNext(_d);
     })
     .then(function(val) {
      //All done
      })
      .catch(err_handler);
```

I want to make it into something like.

```
     getSomethingAsync(something)
     .then(doSomethingAsync)
     .then(doSomethingSync)
     .then(doSomethingAsyncNext)
     .then(function(val) {
      //All done
      })
      .catch(err_handler);
```

Should I just change doSomethingSync  which is:

```
      function(data) {
      // do a lot of things with data, throw errors for invalid data
      return changed_data;
      }
```

to:

```
      function(data) {
      // do a lot of things with data, throw errors for invalid data
      return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
      resolve(changed_data);
      });
      }
```

or:

```
      function(data) {
      return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
      // do a lot of things with data, reject for invalid data
      resolve(changed_data);
      });
      }
```

Comment: To emphasize Felix's point - you don't actually have to promisify it at all - promises let you mix and match.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum  Does that mean, I can still call other functions, even when the last promise in the chain has resolved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Should I just change doSomethingSync which is ...

You don't have to change it all. If the return value of the callback is *not* a promise, it is directly used to resolve the promise returned by `.then`. The `.then` callback does not *have* to return a promise.

You *could* write

```
return Promise.resolve(changed_data);
```

but again, there is no need. `return changed_data;` will work just as well.

Comment: Clear and helpful for synchronous function. How about asynchronous function which requires a callback function?

Comment: Then you would simply return a promise from the callback.

Comment: @FelixKling No, you can't return a promise from the callback. You need to promisify the callback-based function as well, separately.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: Sorry for being unclear. I mean the callback passed to `.then`.  That callback would create the promise and call the async function.

Comment: Yes, it worked without changing. but at first when typing the function I made  a typo, .then(doSomethingSymc).. but it didnt throw any error, nor the .catch caught it.

Comment: @FelixKling ^ Ah, so the typo makes it .then(undefined),  what does that do?

Comment: @cswl: `.then(undefined)` is equivalent to `.then(function(x) { return x; })`, i.e.  it just passes the value through. http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-performpromisethen

Comment: @FelixKling Hmm.. that's gonna make some weird bugs.. Anyways, thanks for the clarification,  :)